# Evaluating a binary expression tree with chaining comparison operators

Tags: data-structures, compiler-construction, tree, bison

I'm building a binary expression tree (for a toy scripting language), and so far I have arithmetic operations working fine (i.e. `4 * (5 + 6)`); now I want to add support for comparison operators. This was pretty easy to do with simple binary comparisons like `0 < 1`, but I'm having issues when I chain them together. For example, this expression:

```
0 < 1 < 2
```

Currently produces the following binary expression tree:

```
    <
   / \
  <   2
 / \
0   1
```

I'm using recursion to traverse the tree down to the leaf nodes and return the values back up, so `0 < 1` gets processed first, which (correctly) returns a True. The problem is that the next level up would be comparing `True < 2`, when it should be comparing `True && (1 < 2)`.

What's the best way of fixing this problem? I was thinking I might end up having to build my tree differently. i.e.

```
       &&
      /  \
     /    \
    <      <
   / \    / \
  0   1  1   2
```

But I was hoping for a more elegant/slightly-less-complicated-to-implement-in-my-bison-parser solution.

Comment: Do you really want this? Because users might rely that it works similar to C++ etc. (ie. your abbreviation breaks other things)

Comment: @deviantfan: Maybe the users think it works similarly to python.

Comment: How this question is related to c++?

Comment: @Slava: I included it because my project is written in C++. You're probably right though, it's not that relevant to the problem -- I'll remove the tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In essence, a series of chained comparisons is a single operator, not a series of binary operators. Desugaring `a < b < c` to `(a < b) && (b < c)` is imprecise because it evaluates `b` twice. So you might just desugar it to a n-ary operator, if your AST allows that.

You can also make it work with a sequence of binary operators if you have a discriminated union type. In this case, a very simple discriminated union will be sufficient.

Let `T` be a type whose values are `false` or any integer. (Here, `false` is *distinct* from any integer, so it is not the same as `0`.)

Now, we define `<` as follows:

```
integer a < integer b ==> T
  if a is less than b, then b; otherwise false

T a < integer b ==> T
  if a is false, then false; otherwise a < b (as above)
```

For any use of the intermediate result of a chained comparison, it is necesary to convert the `T` result to a boolean; we do so in the obvious way: `false` maps onto the boolean value false, and any integer maps onto the boolean value true.

The consequence of the implicit conversion to boolean is that

```
a < b == c < d      # Chained comparison
```

is not the same as

```
(a < b) == (c < d)  # Comparison of two booleans
```

This is basically the semantics of Python, for example.
The above could work replacing integer with any orderable type.

---

In order to implement chained comparison, you need to manage parenthesized comparisons correctly in your grammar. The usual naive AST construction which just deletes parentheses will not work.

Comment: This interacts badly with making booleans first-class types that can themselves be compared -- something like `(a < 5) == (b > 3)` becomes very hard to evaluate...

Comment: @ChrisDodd: It's necessary to convert T to a boolean in any context other than the chained comparisons. But that's no different from any other implicit coercion. As with python, `(a < 5) == (b < 3)` is not the same as `a < 5 == b < 3`